# Problema al filtrar opciones de menú con permisos con Laravel y Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Quiero hacer un menú que se genere evaluando los permisos que tenga un usuario. Esa parte funciona bien, pero hay menú anidados que se siguen renderizando aunque queden vacíos.
Hice un script con Javascript para evaluar el contenido de esos elementos HTML y si están vacíos, lo remueva del documento, pero no está funcionando correctamente y no veo cuál es el error.
Este es el script:

```
    function () {
                    menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('has-sub');

                    for(item of menuItems) {
                        content = String.prototype.trim(item.getElementsByClassName('menu-content')[0].innerHTML);

                        if(content == ''){
                            item.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Y este es la estructura del menú vista desde el navegador:

```
<ul class="navigation navigation-main" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">

<li class="nav-item  " id="">
    <a data-uri="admin.mantenimiento.positions.index" href="http://localhost:8000/dashboard"
        class="d-flex align-items-center" target="_self">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            class="feather feather-home">
            <path d="M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z"></path>
            <polyline points="9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22"></polyline>
        </svg>
        <span class="menu-title text-truncate">
            Inicio
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item  " id="">
    <a data-uri="admin.mantenimiento.positions.index" href="http://localhost:8000/dev/clientes/casilla-electronica"
        class="d-flex align-items-center" target="_self">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            class="feather feather-inbox">
            <polyline points="22 12 16 12 14 15 10 15 8 12 2 12"></polyline>
            <path
                d="M5.45 5.11L2 12v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-6l-3.45-6.89A2 2 0 0 0 16.76 4H7.24a2 2 0 0 0-1.79 1.11z">
            </path>
        </svg>
        <span class="menu-title text-truncate">
            Casilla Electrónica
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item  " id="">
    <a data-uri="admin.mantenimiento.positions.index" href="http://localhost:8000/dev/mis-solicitudes"
        class="d-flex align-items-center" target="_self">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            class="feather feather-book">
            <path d="M4 19.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 17H20"></path>
            <path d="M6.5 2H20v20H6.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 4 19.5v-15A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 2z"></path>
        </svg>
        <span class="menu-title text-truncate">
            Mis Solicitudes
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item  " id="">
    <a data-uri="admin.mantenimiento.positions.index" href="http://localhost:8000/dev/mis-respuestas"
        class="d-flex align-items-center" target="_self">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            class="feather feather-book">
            <path d="M4 19.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 17H20"></path>
            <path d="M6.5 2H20v20H6.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 4 19.5v-15A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 2z"></path>
        </svg>
        <span class="menu-title text-truncate">
            Respuestas a Solicitudes
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item  " id="">
    <a data-uri="admin.mantenimiento.positions.index" href="http://localhost:8000/admin/inbox"
        class="d-flex align-items-center" target="_self">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            class="feather feather-inbox">
            <polyline points="22 12 16 12 14 15 10 15 8 12 2 12"></polyline>
            <path
                d="M5.45 5.11L2 12v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-6l-3.45-6.89A2 2 0 0 0 16.76 4H7.24a2 2 0 0 0-1.79 1.11z">
            </path>
        </svg>
        <span class="menu-title text-truncate">
            Bandeja de entrada
        </span>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item has-sub open" id="requests_menu" style="">
    <a data-uri="admin.mantenimiento.positions.index" href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex align-items-center"
        target="_self">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            class="feather feather-book">
            <path d="M4 19.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 17H20"></path>
            <path d="M6.5 2H20v20H6.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 4 19.5v-15A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 2z"></path>
        </svg>
        <span class="menu-title text-truncate">
            Solicitudes
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="menu-content">
        <li>
            <a href="http://localhost:8000/admin/solicitudes/solicitud-arbitraje-fisico"
                class="d-flex align-items-center" target="_self">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                    class="feather feather-corner-down-right">
                    <polyline points="15 10 20 15 15 20"></polyline>
                    <path d="M4 4v7a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h12"></path>
                </svg>
                <span class="menu-item text-truncate">Solicitud de Arbitraje Físico</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-item  " id="">
    <a data-uri="admin.mantenimiento.positions.index" href="http://localhost:8000/admin/mesa-de-partes-virtual"
        class="d-flex align-items-center" target="_self">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            class="feather feather-archive">
            <polyline points="21 8 21 21 3 21 3 8"></polyline>
            <rect x="1" y="3" width="22" height="5"></rect>
            <line x1="10" y1="12" x2="14" y2="12"></line>
        </svg>
        <span class="menu-title text-truncate">
            Mesa de Partes Virtual
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item  " id="">
    <a data-uri="admin.mantenimiento.positions.index" href="http://localhost:8000/admin/mesa-de-partes"
        class="d-flex align-items-center" target="_self">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            class="feather feather-archive">
            <polyline points="21 8 21 21 3 21 3 8"></polyline>
            <rect x="1" y="3" width="22" height="5"></rect>
            <line x1="10" y1="12" x2="14" y2="12"></line>
        </svg>
        <span class="menu-title text-truncate">
            Mesa de Partes
        </span>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item has-sub sidebar-group-active" id="data_menu" style="">
    <a data-uri="admin.mantenimiento.positions.index" href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex align-items-center"
        target="_self">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            class="feather feather-package">
            <line x1="16.5" y1="9.4" x2="7.5" y2="4.21"></line>
            <path
                d="M21 16V8a2 2 0 0 0-1-1.73l-7-4a2 2 0 0 0-2 0l-7 4A2 2 0 0 0 3 8v8a2 2 0 0 0 1 1.73l7 4a2 2 0 0 0 2 0l7-4A2 2 0 0 0 21 16z">
            </path>
            <polyline points="3.27 6.96 12 12.01 20.73 6.96"></polyline>
            <line x1="12" y1="22.08" x2="12" y2="12"></line>
        </svg>
        <span class="menu-title text-truncate">
            Administrar datos
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="menu-content">
        <li>
            <a href="http://localhost:8000/admin/mantenimiento/areas" class="d-flex align-items-center"
                target="_self">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                    class="feather feather-corner-down-right">
                    <polyline points="15 10 20 15 15 20"></polyline>
                    <path d="M4 4v7a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h12"></path>
                </svg>
                <span class="menu-item text-truncate">Áreas</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="http://localhost:8000/admin/mantenimiento/cargos" class="d-flex align-items-center"
                target="_self">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                    class="feather feather-corner-down-right">
                    <polyline points="15 10 20 15 15 20"></polyline>
                    <path d="M4 4v7a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h12"></path>
                </svg>
                <span class="menu-item text-truncate">Cargos</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://localhost:8000/admin/mantenimiento/tipo-documentos" class="d-flex align-items-center"
                target="_self">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                    class="feather feather-corner-down-right">
                    <polyline points="15 10 20 15 15 20"></polyline>
                    <path d="M4 4v7a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h12"></path>
                </svg>
                <span class="menu-item text-truncate">Tipo de documentos</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Así se ve el menú luego del filtado, pero no deberia aparecer "Solicitudes", ya que el usuario no tiene permiso de ninguna de las opciones que hay dentro:

[image: Menú]

Comment: Deberías mostrar el código de como construyes el menú, pienso que debes solucionarlo desde ahí y no con Javascript

Comment: Alguien ya me ayudó. Lo resolvimos con un contador y unos condicionales usando PHP. Gracias de todas formas!

Comment: Es la mejor solución, controlarlo antes de la salida.  De todos modos ya lo tenias, tan solo no estabas llamando a la funcion de ningun modo y no se estaba ejecutando. Si miras aqui lo veras: https://jsfiddle.net/u61oswvL/